# mysql installer did not find packages in the current bundle suitable for installation windows

Tags: mysql, windows-10

I am trying to install MySQL 8.0.23 version from the [download page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html). I ran the .msi file several times and every time, I got the error "mysql installer did not find packages in the current bundle suitable for installation windows". I tried to find a solution online for more than an hour and I could not get the resolution to problem. I even ran it through CMD using admin privileges and still no use. I am installing on a laptop with the following configuration.

Windows 10, 64Bit with 16GB RAM, i7 Hexacore, 1TB SSD.

Can someone please help?

Comment: May I know why the question is being voted for closure? If you know the answer or the link to the solution, please post.

Comment: You may get better answers on superuser.com or askdifferent.com about how to get MySql running again for long enough to use mysqldump to grab your data.

Answer (score 26):

I suspect there is currently a server issue or something on Oracle/MySQL's end, I have tried the 8.0.22 and 5.7.33 Web installers and neither of them are able to find the list of packages to install.

One solution is to download the larger offline installer.

First you must uninstall the `MySQL Web Installer`, this can be done by opening Apps & Features, finding `MySQL Installer - Community` and clicking Uninstall.

Then from the MySQL Downloads page, download the larger 400MB MSI installer, once launched you should see a list of `Available Products` to choose from

Comment: I had the no-packages issue with the full MySQL 8 installer.

Comment: @Evan perhaps try uninstall the old installer first, doing this changed the page I saw when first launching the MySQL Installer to a list of Available Products

Comment: Eventually the packages started showing. It must've been a hiccup. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me. I started with the smaller web based installer. To fix the issue uninstall the mysql installer. Then download the larger offline installer and run that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14):

**Uninstalling** the *"MySQL Installer - Community"* and redownloading and installing the full installer ~422MB from [Downloads page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

After wasting so much time, I find the solution to install MySQL 8 on Windows x64 (64-bit) system.

1. Run the msi installer
2. Next (Even it wouldn't work)
3. Go to below path instead

   `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Product Cache`
4. Right click -> Install

```
mysql-8.0.23-winx64.msi
mysql-connector-c++-8.0.23-win32.msi
mysql-connector-c++-8.0.23-winx64.msi
mysql-connector-java-gpl-8.0.23.msi
mysql-connector-net-8.0.23.msi
mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.23-win32.msi
mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.23-winx64.msi
mysql-connector-python-8.0.23-windows-x86-32bit.msi
mysql-connector-python-8.0.23-windows-x86-64bit.msi
mysql-documents-8.0.23.msi
mysql-examples-8.0.23.msi
mysql-router-8.0.23-winx64.msi
mysql-shell-8.0.23-windows-x86-64bit.msi
mysql-workbench-community-8.0.23-winx64.msi
```

Answer (score 1):

If nothhing else works, click on `Looking for Previous GA versions?` and downloaded the one with 500 ~ MB and that did the job for me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues and tried the solutions above which none worked for me.
I did the following and it worked:

- In Add/Remove programs from the control panel uninstall all MySQL entries.
- Delete all MySQL folders from C:\Program Files\MySQL
- Make a restart to your computer
- Reinstall using the large MSI installer (more than 400MB)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of steps. Uninstalling and installing it again for current version 8.0.23.
Following steps fixed the below error for me:

> No Packages error MySQL did not find packages in the current bundle
> suitable for Installation No Compatible servers were found.

Step 1: At first, uninstall and remove MySQL. That includes, uninstalling completely and removing all the remaining MySQL folders from the system.

Step2: Restart the system. Go to the official [MySQL website Downloads section](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/). On reaching, install the 2nd MySQL version (the larger one) as shown in the [tutorial](https://studyopedia.com/errors-resolved/fix-mysql-no-packages-found-error/).

mysql-installer-community-8.0.23.0.msi

After downloading, under Setup Type, you need to choose Developer Default and keep all other steps similar.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

I try on Windows 10 Home edition.

I also try with version 8.0.22: same error.

EDIT 1 18/01/21 : also with large MSI installer (more than 400MB)

EDIT 2 19/01/21 : The problem has fixed. This was probably a problem on the mysql download servers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was uninstalling MySql Workbench and the installer and then running the installer msi from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the (mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.23.0.msi) one and download the (mysql-installer-community-8.0.23.0.msi) one. If still not working, right click uninstall, and then right click install again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used the bigger download package, mysql-installer-community-8.0.30.0 with 450M. Then I see below image along the way, clicking "Add", then picked the workbench, then green button appeared to move to the right pane, then "execute". Workbench is then installed

[image]